# Assigning color in C# overrides Style. How can I prevent this?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to make customizable `DataGrid`. I have a problem. I have researched but i couldn't find anything about it.

I created a `Style` for cells. In this style, there is an `MultiTrigger` like in the code below.

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
   <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="True"/>
      <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.Tek_Satiri_Guncelleme_Modu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGrid_Ozellestirilebilir}}}" Value="False"/>
   </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

This `Multitrigger` works perfectly as expected like this;

This is static state -->[image: Static State]

When cell is in focused-->[image]

Then in C#, I change the color of cell like this.

```
//Get row    
DataGridRow dataGridRow = (DataGridRow)DataGrid_1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(5);
//Get cell    
DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)DataGrid_1.Columns[5].GetCellContent(dataGridRow).Parent;
cell.BorderBrush = Brushes.White; //This color i see when cell is in focus.
```

When i run the application this code overrides (i guess) my custom `Style` and i cant see Blue when the cell is in focus. I see White.

Border color turned to white as expected-->[image]

This what i should see when cell is in focus. But i see white instead.-->[image]

Can anyone help me about this situation?

### Edit:

thatguy made very good explanation about this situation and gave two solutions. But there is a problem. This solutions work for only one color. So if I want to change the color of more than one cell, they must all be the same color. I need to adjust the colors of different cells differently. Is there any solution for this situation too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the precedence of a local value over a `Style` trigger, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list).

> 3. Local value. A local value might be set through the convenience of the "wrapper" property, which also equates to setting as an attribute or property element in XAML, [...]

> 6. Style triggers. The triggers within styles from page or application (these styles might be either explicit or implicit styles, but not from the default styles, which have lower precedence).

To solve this problem, you could use one of the following options.

- Try to integrate the `White` color with additional triggers into your existing style
- Create another style based on your current style and add a setter for the color `White` and assign this style to the cells that need to be styled differently

  ```
  <Style x:Key="MySpecialCellStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyCellStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
  </Style>
  ```

  ```
  cell.Style = (Style)FindResource("MySpecialCellStyle");
  ```

Comment: Thanks for very good explanation. But there is a problem i have. This works for only one color. What if I want to adjust the colors of different cells differently? I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: @Schiaparelli If I undertand you correctly, it is the same, either adapt your style by creating additional triggers for the states that require different colors or create a specialized style for each case and assign it to the corresponding cells. As the base style contains most of the triggers and setters that are inherited to the specialized styles, those will be minimal as in this example.